# Email 'rules' for Outlook.com and Outlook 2013

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, hotmail, outlook.com

I was under the assumption that when I make a rule in Outlook 2013, which is ActiveSync'd to my Outlook.com account, it makes that as a server rule (unless something in my rule makes it impossible to run on the server).

But when I set up an Outlook 2013 server rule it up and then try to confirm it via the email rules on Outlook.com, I don't see it. I do see other rules I had setup on the Outlook.com portal but not this one which I setup from inside Outlook 2013.

**Question #1**: My outlook 2013 rule is a server rule, right? (image below). I know previously the UI would explicitly say it so and the absence meant it's a server rule.

**Quesiton #2**: Are Outlook 2013 server rules entirely different from the Outlook.com server rules? If not, does someone know what's going on?

---

The rule in Outlook 2013 is as shown below and it does work:

[image]

The view inside Outlook.com's rules is shown below (you can see it missing the above Outlook 2013 server rule)

[image]

Comment: Also note (according to your screenshots), your rules that show in OWA don't show in Outlook either.  If you have Outlook 2013 open, running  and connected when you look at OWA, does it change anything?

Comment: @techie007: Good point. Outlook 2013 was open while I was logged into Outlook.com (OWA?) when those screenshots were taken. So I guess the response is it doesn't change anything :/

Answer (score 0):

Here are the answers:

1. No, these rules are not server-side. Although they are stored on the server.
2. Since these rules are not server-side, they are different.

Comment: Do you know how I could reframe the rule so that it becomes a server-side rule? It's a very simple rule, probably as basic as a rule can be, so I don't understand why it should not run on the server.

Comment: No way. For now outlook.com provides its own rules.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook rule definitely isn't a server side rule since it's based on the contents of the subject line, and that makes it a client only rule. See http://www.msoutlook.info/question/371 for a good guide on those things which will cause a rule to be client side, or even "this machine only" rules.